# Ogr2ogr does not support file name with non-ASCII character?

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I tried to use the following script to convert shapefile to mif:

```
ogr2ogr -f "MapInfo File" D:\docs\arcgis_data\shp_mif\BOU.mif D:\docs\arcgis_data\shp\BOU.shp
```

it works.

But I found that if the name of the shapefile has non-ASCII characters like this:

```
D:\docs\arcgis_data\shp\臺北.shp
```

Then the covert will fail with message:

```
Unable to open datasource `D:\docs\arcgis_data\shp\臺北.shp' with the following drivers
......
```

Any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Files with non-ASCII names are not supported as you can see here:

https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues/40